# How to call Grid from within CS file in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid

Unable to call a grid inside a listbox anymore... my xaml is as follows.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFPurpleButtonTest.InstrumentUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFPurpleButtonTest"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="750" d:DesignWidth="900">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="706" Margin="24,34,0,-212" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="850" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <TabItem Header="TabItem" Name="mainTab">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" Margin="0,0,-396,-255">
                    <Label x:Name="colourName" Content="PURPLE" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="93" Margin="284,88,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="243" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" Foreground="#FFDC00FF"/>
                    <Button x:Name="testButton" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="365,181,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="TestButton_Click"/>
                    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Row Size" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="198,211,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFDC00FF"/>
                    <Label x:Name="label_Copy" Content="Column Size" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="432,211,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFDC00FF"/>
                    <Button x:Name="createGrid" Content="Create Grid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="365,273,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="CreateGrid_Click"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="rowSizeText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="278,214,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="62"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="columnSizeText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="522,215,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="62"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="TabItem" Name="gridTab">
                <ListBox x:Name="listbox1" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Vertical" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <Viewbox>
                                    <Grid x:Name="wellGrid" Grid.Row="1" ShowGridLines="True"
                      local:GridHelpers.RowCount="{Binding RowCount}"
                      local:GridHelpers.ColumnCount="{Binding ColumnCount}" Margin="15,15,15,15" />
                                </Viewbox>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I want to be able to call wellGrid.Children like I used to when the grid was not in a listbox but not entirely sure how to do that now the grid is in the listbox.

Comment: It will be in ListBox resources. Because it is a data template. Why do you want to call that grid anyway? All of your UI items are fixed, is that by design? It looks like this UC was created using the designer.

Comment: hey XAMIMAX, i want to call the Grid because I populate it dynamically with content in my CS file... I used to create new buttons based on row count and column count supplied on the fly and the grid would be populated... but now i don't know how to do that...

Comment: Also listbox1.Resources is empty

Comment: The Grid should be in a UserControl, which would also contain the code to populate it from the item data. In the UserControl's code behind you can access the associated item via the DataContext property.

Comment: Hi Clemens, as you can see from the XAML it is in a UserControl. How would I access the data from the DataContext? Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

The `Grid is part of the`DataTemplate`that is assigned to the`ListBoxItem`. You need to get the`ContentPresenter`of the item. This is where the`DataTemplate` is applied.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  int selectedItemIndex = this.listbox1.SelectedIndex;
  if (selectedItemIndex == -1)
  {
    return;
  }

  var itemContainer = this.listbox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(selectedItemIndex) as ListBoxItem;

  if (TryFindChildElement(itemContainer, out ContentPresenter contentPresenter))
  {
    // Get the Grid
    var grid = contentPresenter.ContentTemplate.FindName("wellGrid", myContentPresenter) as Grid;    
  }
}

// Helper to traverse the visual tree
private bool TryFindChildElement<TElement>(DependencyObject parent, out TElement resultElement) where TElement : DependencyObject
{
  resultElement = null;
  for (var childIndex = 0; childIndex < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); childIndex++)
  {
    DependencyObject childElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, childIndex);

    if (childElement is Popup popup)
    {
      childElement = popup.Child;
    }

    if (childElement is TElement)
    {
      resultElement = childElement as TElement;
      return true;
    }

    if (TryFindChildElement(childElement, out resultElement))
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```